# approximate definite integrals using quadrature approximation

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

I understand that we are looking for the Q formula that has the highest possible degree of precision
Why do we stop at $x^2$?
[image: The exercise :]

Comment: because you only have 3 unknowns involved. Having a higher order will make your system overdetermined.

Comment: Thank you, it's clearer, now.